# Subclasses and return types

Tags: scala, covariance, subtype

let's say I wanted to have something like the following:

```
abstract class PDF[T, S <: PDF[T, _]] {
  def fit(obs: Seq[T], weights: Seq[Double]): S
}

class PDFGaussian(val mu: Double, val Sigma: Double) extends PDF[Double, PDFGaussian] {
  def fit(obs: Seq[Double], weights: Seq[Double]): PDFGaussian =
    new PDFGaussian(...) // bla bla bla
}
```

So, basically, what I want is to have the `fit` function to return an instance of the type of its *enclosing* class which obviously must be a subclass of `PDF[T]`.
However, instead of having to use the double parameterization `PDF[T, S <: PDF[T, _]]` I'd rather go with only one type parameter like so:

```
abstract class PDF[T] {
  def fit[S <: PDF[T]](obs: Seq[T], weights: Seq[Double]): S
}

class PDFGaussian(val mu: Double, val Sigma: Double) extends PDF[Double] {
  def fit[S <: PDF[_]](obs: Seq[Double], weights: Seq[Double]): S =
    new PDFGaussian(...) // bla bla bla
}
```

If I do this, however, the compiler yells at me for returning `PDFGaussian` instead of `S`. Since I'm obviously missing some important fact about scala's type system here could you please clarify what I'm doing wrong and show me how to do it with only one type parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first solution is pretty good, IMHO. But let's talk about the questions. First, about what is wrong here:

```
abstract class PDF[T] {
  def fit[S <: PDF[T]](obs: Seq[T], weights: Seq[Double]): S
}

class PDFGaussian(val mu: Double, val Sigma: Double) extends PDF[Double] {
  def fit[S <: PDF[_]](obs: Seq[Double], weights: Seq[Double]): S =
    new PDFGaussian(...) // bla bla bla
}
```

Let's say I have

```
class FooBar extends PDF[Double] { ... }
```

And I do:

```
val pdfg = new PDFGaussian(1.0, -1.0)
val foobar = pdfg.fit[FooBar](List(0.5, 0.75), List(4, 2))
```

So, I'm telling the compiler that I want `S` to be `FooBar`, but you are returning `PDFGaussian`! That's what the compiler is complaining about.

So, how to solve it? Well... tough. :-) How about this:

```
abstract class PDF[T] {
  type S <: PDF[T]
  def fit(obs: Seq[T], weights: Seq[Double]): S
}

class PDFGaussian(val mu: Double, val Sigma: Double) extends PDF[Double] {
  type S = PDFGaussian
  def fit(obs: Seq[Double], weights: Seq[Double]): S =
    new PDFGaussian(...) // bla bla bla
}
```

It's a bit more verbose, but it keeps `PDF` type signature cleaner.

Comment: Thank you! I do now understand what I've been doing wrong thanks to your "FooBar" explanation. My primary goal is to keep the signature clear so this is exactly what has been sought.